# Areas don't add up using Raster Calculator & and Tabulate Area

Tags: arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, arcgis-10.8, tabulate

I'm using & (AND) in Raster Calculator for two rasters and then using Tabulate area to work out the area of each in a polygon layer. But the amount in the resulting table is more than the amount for just one of the rasters.

That cannot possibly be so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are they overlapping? If not maybe the coordinate system is not properly set?

Comment: Ok, I'm thinking there's a cell size mismatch.

Comment: Thanks Soph, I had projected everything to the same equal area projection and when I use the unprotected version the differences are much smaller. I'll try resampling to a common size and see if that fixes it.